# Laravel 5.6.26 on PHP72 Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

I have a fresh Laravel 5.6.26 project on my CENTOS 7. After creating the database and setted up the .env file with required information I ran php artisan migrate and exceptions were thrown, however, I can access the database by the Laravel application using Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB and I have the PDO installed.

[image: Laravel 5.6 PDO could not find driver]

[image: PHP72 PDO]

[image: PHP72 PDO]

[image: PHP72 PDO]

Comment: Do you have multiple php versions installed?  Does your phpinfo show 7.2.7?  Does `php -v`?  The mysqlnd version doesn't look like a 7.2 build to me.

Comment: Just checking, but if you just installed MySQL, have you restarted Apache/Nginx?

Comment: I do not believe (yet!) But I think it's the lack of the "php-mysqlnd" package, however, I had already installed the package "php72-php-mysqlnd". php72-php-mysqlnd version 7.2.7 | Release 1.el7.remi | -- Size 427 k --. php-mysqlnd version 7.2.7 | Release 1.el7.remi | -- Size 862 k --. I will do a new installation to validate, but "apparently" it worked